# how to read and write the FlutterSecureStorage in public package in flutter

Tags: flutter

Because many of my apps would use `FlutterSecureStorage`, so I define the `FlutterSecureStorage` in a public lib like this:

```
bool isLoggedIn = false;
String baseUrl = "";
String shareUrl = "";
String staticResourceUrl = "";
final pageStorageBucket = PageStorageBucket();
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

enum ConfigType { DEV, PRO }

class GlobalConfig {}
```

I could expose the GlobalConfig in main.dart like this in public lib:

```
export 'src/config/global_config.dart';
```

but I just wanna to know how to use the `storage` after import the public lib in my app, I am using the public lib in my app like this:

```
  wheel:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/wheel.git
      ref: main
```

how to read and write global `FlutterSecureStorage` when add dependencies of  wheel lib? is it possible? or define the `FlutterSecureStorage` in each app is the best practice? or what should I do use the `FlutterSecureStorage` global?

Answer (score 0):

I define a secure storage util class:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorageUtil{

  static FlutterSecureStorage _preferences = FlutterSecureStorage();

  static Future<String?> getString (String key, {String defValue = ''}) {
    return _preferences.read(key:key) ;
  }

  static Future<void> putString(String key, String value) {
    return _preferences.write(key:key, value:value);
  }

}
```

use it like this:

```
SecureStorageUtil.putString("token", "1");
```